# Extract content with Perl

Tags: regex, perl, text-processing

I'd like to write a parsing script in Perl that prints all the "interface name" from these bunch of data:

```
interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.1 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 30
    0:  53 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65 20 4c 6f 6f 70 62 61 63     Software Loopbac
    16:  6b 20 49 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 20 31 00 -- --     k Interface 1...

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.2 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 53 53     WAN Miniport (SS
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.3 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 4c 32     WAN Miniport (L2
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............
```

I'd like to extract all the three interfaces' name out, as ("Sotware Loopback Interface 1", "WAN Miniport (SSTP)", "WAN Miniport (L2TP)"), and do further processing. I tried using regular expression but without luch. Is there any simple way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks more like an `unpack` problem than a regular expression problem; the input data is well structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another dirty perl script. Read your data into $text however you wish. The regular expression looks for the pattern of each hex dump line. The join line then recombines the hex values back into the string and appends it to the current accumulated interface name. mttrb's is simpler.  ;)

```
$text =<<EOM;
interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.1 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 30
    0:  53 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65 20 4c 6f 6f 70 62 61 63     Software Loopbac
    16:  6b 20 49 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 20 31 00 -- --     k Interface 1...

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.2 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 53 53     WAN Miniport (SS
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.3 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 4c 32     WAN Miniport (L2
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............
EOM

$interface = "";
foreach $line (split(/\n/, $text)) {
  next unless $line =~ /\b(\d+):\s+((?:[0-9a-fA-F-]{2} ){16})/;
  if ($1 == 0) {
    print "$interface\n" if $interface;
    $interface = "";
  }
  $interface .= join('', map { chr(hex($_)) } grep { $_ ne '--' && $_ ne '00' } split(/ /, $2));
}
print "$interface\n" if $interface;
```

To explain the join line, the following things occur in that line.

1. split(/ /, $2) - Takes the second saved group from the regular expression, which are the hex characters, and splits it into an array containing each pair of digits.
2. grep { $_ ne '--' && $_ ne '00' } - Looks through the digit pair array and filters out the '--' and '00' entries, leaving only valid values.
3. map { chr(hex($*)) } - Runs the expression against each of the filtered pairs, $* being the pair being processed. Hex parses it from a hex() string into a number and then chr() takes that number and translates it into the corresponding character.
4. join('', ...) - Takes in the array of characters that map created and creates a single string out of them. The '' is the string to separate each array item with, in this case nothing.

Comment: +1 for using the hex instead. `pack 'H*', $string` can also be used, after removing the padding.

Comment: @Avilo Can you explain more details on the line `$interface .= join('', map { chr(hex($_)) } grep { $_ ne '--' && $_ ne '00' } split(/ /, $2));` Trying to understand, but getting a little confused, sorry I'm new to perl.

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't help!

Answer (score 1):

The following is a quick and dirty perl script that will do what you want, given the example input.  It won't handle changes in the input format very gracefully.  I have written the script to take input from a file, you will need to change this.

```
open(INPUT, "interfaces.txt");

my $interface;

while(<INPUT>) {
        if (/^\s*0:/) {
                $interface = substr($_, 60, 16);
        } elsif (/^\s*16:/) {
                $interface .= substr($_, 61, 16);

                $interface =~ s/\.+$//;

                print $interface, "\n";
        }
}

close(INPUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using paragraph mode (setting `$/ = ""`) you can read each record and process the lines individually. Grabbing the last field seems to be easiest done with `split` on whitespace using a fixed `LIMIT` on the fields, as the number of hex numbers seems to be constant, and we want the last field.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "";  # paragraph mode keeps lines together

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;   # removes two newlines after we changed $/
    my ($hdr, @data) = split /\n/; # header + 2 lines
    my ($interface, @nums) = getdata(@data);
    print Dumper $interface;
}
sub getdata {
    my (@hex, $str);
    my @data = @_;
    for (@data) {
        push @hex, split(' ', $_, 18);  # LIMIT set to 18
        $str .= pop @hex;               # last field is our string
    }
    return $str, @hex;   # return everything, why not?
}

__DATA__
interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.1 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 30
    0:  53 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65 20 4c 6f 6f 70 62 61 63     Software Loopbac
    16:  6b 20 49 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 20 31 00 -- --     k Interface 1...

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.2 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 53 53     WAN Miniport (SS
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.3 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 4c 32     WAN Miniport (L2
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = 'Software Loopback Interface 1...';
$VAR1 = 'WAN Miniport (SSTP).............';
$VAR1 = 'WAN Miniport (L2TP).............';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using regex.

```
use strict ;
use warnings;
my $Data = '
interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.1 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 30
    0:  53 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65 20 4c 6f 6f 70 62 61 63     Software Loopbac
    16:  6b 20 49 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 20 31 00 -- --     k Interface 1...

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.2 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 53 53     WAN Miniport (SS
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............

interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.3 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): (hex): length = 20
    0:  57 41 4e 20 4d 69 6e 69 70 6f 72 74 20 28 4c 32     WAN Miniport (L2
    16:  54 50 29 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     TP).............
';

foreach my $Record ( $Data =~ m#\G(.+?)(?:(?=^\s*$)|\z)#gsm)  {
    my $Interface = '';
    foreach ( split /\n/, $Record ) {
        next if /^\s*$/;
        next if /OCTET STRING/i;
        (m#^[^:]+:(?:\s*(?:\w\w|--)\s*){16}(.+)$#);
        $Interface .= "$1";
    }

    print "$Interface\n";
}
```